# Why doesn't the eigenfrequency of a bottle change with different temperatures?

Tags: temperature, acoustics

So I thought I had a smart idea to measure the temperature by blowing on a bottle. I had the idea that inside (20 degrees celsius) it would have a certain eigenfrequency e.g. 240 Hz and outside it would have a different eigenfrequency because the temperature is around 0 degrees celsius, thus the speed of sound changes. However when I tested it it was still the same eigenfrequency. I even waited a while. I was quite disapointed, I thought I had a good idea. Is it maybe because the air you blow on it is pretty warm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you think this happens because the speed of sound changes with temperature? But did you do any initial calculation to see how much the speed changes and how much that would change the frequency? If it is a very small change in frequency you may not be able to measure it.

Comment: Also, are you asking about the theory in general or your specific experiment?

Comment: Also, what tool are you using to measure the frequency? How accurate is it? Can it measure a change of a couple Hz? If so, you can probably measure the change, but you might not be able to hear it with your ear.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My question is is why I got a null result. I measure with a smartphone and the phyphox app, it seems to have a resolution of around 0.1 hz at least. It shows to 0.01 hz but I don't know if it properly can distinguish those frequencies.

Comment: It seems like your question is pretty vague and will be difficult to get a good answer on this forum. The answer likely has to do with your experimental setup and so it could be one of any number of things.

Comment: But how is my question vague? I either measured wrong or I should not be expecting a non-null result.

Comment: In what way did you measure wrong? It could be a thousand different things.

Comment: The question of whether or not you should be expecting a "non-null result" seems to have already been answered by Farcher's answer post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your theory is that the frequency of the sound wave in the air outside the bottle will be temperature independent and equal to the frequency of the sound wave emerging from the bottle.
So if you keep the air inside the bottle at $20^\circ \rm C$ and emitted sound has a frequency of $240\,\rm Hz$ then that is the frequency of the sound that you would hear and that frequency will be independent of the temperature of the air outside the bottle.

On the other hand if you change the temperature of the air inside the bottle the frequency that you hear will change as the speed of sound, $c$, is proportional to $\sqrt {T(\rm K)}$ and $c=f \lambda$ where the wavelength of the sound wave in the bottle at resonance is only dependent on the geometry of the bottle.
Thus $f \propto \sqrt T \Rightarrow \dfrac {\Delta f}{f} = \dfrac {\Delta T}{2\,T}$ and so for a $5\,\rm K$ change in temperature from $20^\circ \rm C \,(= 293 \rm\, K)$ the frequency will change by approximately $2\,\rm Hz$.

Excitation by blowing across the top of the bottle may well alter the temperature of the air inside the bottle.

This dependence of the frequency on the temperature is very important when tuning and playing a pipe organ as shown in the video [How Temperature Affects Organ Pipe Tuning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_KHRCedopo).

Comment: Thanks for clarification of the theory. However this doesn't explain why I get a null result then? Because with your estimation a 20 degree change would have a 8 Hz difference. I do the measurement with my smartphone and phyphox android app. It seems to have a pretty good resolution, >0.1 Hz it says. The air I blow is approx 37 degrees celsius I think but still that won't quickly heat up the bottle and the air around it.

Comment: I know understand the your inside and outside refers to being inside and outside a building.  It must be that blowing does change the temperature of the air inside the bottle.  So what about trying to blow across the mouth of the bottle using a straw which may help to maintain a low temperature in the bottle or blow (via a straw) across a lump of ice before the mouth of the bottle?

Comment: Those are good ideas. Maybe it doesnt work because only the small part is resonating in the upperpart which can be heated up quite quick. I also found out that the resolution of the phyphox app is pretty bad ( I checked with a tone generator online). I have to check later how I can improve this.